# Propagate a return to the WMS with Shippingbo

Tags: api, wms, oms

My company uses Shippingbo as an OMS and WMS

I try to create a return order from the OMS to the WMS

The return order is rightly created in my OMS but not in my WMS and I have to trigger the propagation in the UI and I would like to do it automaticaly

The request I made:

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://app.shippingbo.com/returns_orders \
  --header 'X-API-USER: my_user' \
  --header 'X-API-TOKEN: passwd' \
  --header 'X-API-VERSION: 1' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "source": "Prestashop-staging",
  "source_ref": "XMLPJGHU",
  "reason": "Bad size",
  "reason_ref": "S/M",
  "return_order_type": "return_order_customer",
  "return_order_expected_items_attributes": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "user_ref": "shirt-and-flag"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add an additional parameter that is the `supplier_id`

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://app.shippingbo.com/returns_orders \
  --header 'X-API-USER: my_user' \
  --header 'X-API-TOKEN: passwd' \
  --header 'X-API-VERSION: 1' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "source": "Prestashop-staging",
  "source_ref": "XMLPJGHU",
  "reason": "Bad size",
  "reason_ref": "S/M",
  "return_order_type": "return_order_customer",
  "supplier_id": __your_id__,
  "return_order_expected_items_attributes": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "user_ref": "shirt-and-flag"
    }
  ]
}'
```

To get the supplier_id you can request:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://app.shippingbo.com/suppliers/available_for_return_order \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Don't forget to add your credentials in the header